# How can I find out the name of an array causing a crash by address on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, crash, nsarray

So I keep getting this crash and break in my code, but I can't figure out exactly where it's coming from. Xcode doesn't break on the line that is relevant to this, and I looked through all of the thread stacks and none of them show the break. Here is what I am getting:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** 
Collection <CALayerArray: 0x17746b10> was mutated while being enumerated.'
```

My question is, how so I find out where this array is? Is there some way to look it up in the Xcode console by address to point me to what exactly is happening here? I can't find where I would be mutating some array just by eyeballing my code.

Comment: Have you tried to add an Exception breakpoint?  What version of xcode are you using?

Comment: address is useless after the program terminated. however, the error message is very clear that you have threading issue. check you are not passing array between threads

Comment: it's problem with threading ,put that method on main thread of UI.that's at..

Comment: It's possible to get that error without a threading problem.  All it takes is modifying an object while in a `for each` loop.

Answer (score 6):

Add exception breakpoint and check the location for crash.

1) Go to the breakpoint navigator.

[image]

2) At the bottom left corner click on the ADD

[image]

3) Now select "Add Exception Bearkpoint" in that.

[image]

4) Make sure "Exception Breakpoint" is enabled.

[image]

5) Right click on breakpoint and Change the exception type to Objective-C.

[image]

Now run you app and debug the crash area.

Comment: Note: you will break at the exception but that will be prior to the error message, you will probably need to continue once or twice th get the full error message. Also it you are using CoreData you may hit exception breakpoints in it, a real PITA.

Comment: @βhargavḯ @ Dilip - Still am facing the same issue. Is there any other way to find the exact location and the array where the crash is occurring.

Comment: @Ethan Allen did u find any solution for that crash. Help in this regard is highly appreciable.